# Display Username, Amount Based on Current Date as against date amount was loaded

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

| Date | Username | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/6/2022 | Klington | 3000 |
| 12/6/2022 | Claire | 5000 |
| 12/6/2022 | Sainz | 32000 |
| 12/6/2022 | Slip | 5000 |

I have tried using index match likewise VlooUP to list all the amount based on current date today().

Comment: Does your version of Excel support the `FILTER` function?

Comment: I don't think so I use Excel 2010